# why is my bottom cloud is not taking the css style like the top cloud?

Tags: html, css, css-position

i cant control my bottom cloud position i cant do anything with bottom cloud and i couldnt find a soloution to it
why is my bottom cloud is not taking the css style like the top cloud????
i cant control my bottom cloud position i cant do anything with bottom cloud and i couldnt find a soloution to it
why is my bottom cloud is not taking the css style like the top cloud????

```css
body{
  background-color: #e4f9f5;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.top-con{
  background-color: #e4f9f5;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px ;
}
.mid-con{
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.bot-con{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.pro{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.top-cloud{
  position: absolute;
  right: 300px;
  top: 50px;
}

.bottom-cloud{
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  bottom: 300px;
}
h1{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Abdulrahman</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="top-con">
    
            <img class="top-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud">
    
            <h1>I Am Abdulrahman.</h1> 
            
            <p>A <span class="pro">pro</span>grammer</p>
    
           <img class="bottom-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud">
    
            <img class="bot-mount" src="images/mountain.png" alt="mountain">
    
        </div>
        <div class="mid-con"></div>
        <div class="bot-con"></div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change bottom property on `.bottom-cloud` like `bottom:50px;` or `top:50px;`

Answer (score 0):

Change CSS on `.bottom-cloud`

```
.bottom-cloud{
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    top: 50px; /* change here */
}
```

Comment: still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

position bottom-cloud also from the top. it works

[image]